# Google Map API v2 Key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-ads-api

Is it complusary to create Map API Key after enabling the "Google Maps Android v2" ??
Because I tried alot but I always failed to run app of Google Map. Please tell me if anyone has tried this. Thanks.

Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.anshul"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
   <permission
    android:name="com.anshul.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-permission android:name="com.anshul.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.anshul.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="------removed-------" />
   </application>

   </manifest>
```

Comment: What errors or exceptions do you have? [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) is good manual how to install google maps

Comment: can you post your application manifest code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the API Key is compulsory, otherwise Google won't authorize your app to use maps.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

To get an API Key goto the Google API Console:
https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Ensure "Google Maps Android API v2" is checked and then goto API Access and click
"Create New Android Key...."

This allows you to enter your package name i.e "com.example.whatever" and your SHA-1 fingerprint (which can be grabbed from eclipse or using keytool). All information can be found in the above link.

Good luck

Comment: I have done this a long time ago. And I've tried so many codes but nothing is worth for me.

Comment: It sounds like you're having a problem with the SHA-1. You can add multiple SHA-1s to your API key.
Try opening eclipse preferences then goto Android -> Build. Copy the debug SHA1 Fingerprint you are using.

Now you should edit your allowed applications and paste in a big string of SHA1s, like this:

45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example
11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:11:01:11;com.example

Comment: Should I create a new SH-1?

Comment: Sure, you normally have a debug one which you use when you run your app connected via USB cable. Plus another that is signed and used when you release your app. Add them both to the list of allowed apps.
Remember to be specific with the format
SHA1;packagname

Comment: can you please tell me in brief where I should paste that debug's SHA1??

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/project  
-> click project name  
-> "APIs & Auth"  
-> "Credentials"  
-> "Create New Key"  
-> "Android Key"

Comment: Now I have created one more different API key with the same SHA!. Can you plz tell me how I should use them and which one should use first?

Comment: I got like this
**MD5** 45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17
**SHA1** 45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0
SHA256: 45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0:45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0
**Signature alogorithm name : SHA256withRSA**
**Version : 3**

Comment: I'm not sure what that is Anshul? 
If that's what's in your google developer console you need to delete that. You should have:
SHA1 semi-colon package name
45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example.yourappname

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ofcourse its must necessary to create Google Map Api key, without it, how could you success to load the map. You must need to give that key to Android Manifest file's map api key attribute. ITS MUST NECESSARY.

Comment: Pratik I know that. I'm asking that api key can be created or not before enabling "Google Maps Android v2"

Comment: Yes, you can create whenever you want to do it. You just need SHA-1 and your package name, go to api access and follow steps there. After that also you can enable google map android v2 service.

Comment: I have created it a long time ago but it didnt work. I have changed my code many times but no good result :/

Comment: But you have to create 2 keys, one for debuging and one from to make it live. I mean when you run and test it on your device, for that use debug key and when you done with app and going to create apk at that time use live key.

Comment: I've created both. But I can see only one in prefrences>android>build Debug key. How can i find cutoms?

Comment: I've created new key but both SHA1 keys are exactly same but API keys are different. Is it okay?

Comment: yes its ok...no worries for it, it must be different.

Comment: When you are developing at that timeuse debug key, and when you gonna make apk at that time use live key.

Answer (score 0):

This is only because of wrong SHA so use the following code to get the correct SHA of your project.

```
    try {

        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "Your PAckage here", 
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    //              //              System.out.println("KEY HASH.........."+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("name not found...."+e);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                System.out.println("NoSuchAlgorithmException...."+e);
            }
```